# Trying to call a method that displays the method and returns a value for input

Tags: java, loops, input, methods

I'm trying to display the menu first, as well as setting the value for choice. I didn't want to combine choice input with the display menu but those were the instructions. Hoping someone can help me figure out why it won't work. I'm new to using and calling methods so I appreciate any help.

Essentially, it is supposed to be a simple calculator on a loop but also has a quit button.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    displayMenu(int choice);

    while (choice != 6){
        if(choice == 1){
            System.out.print("Enter two numbers to add: ");
            int num1 = scan.nextInt();
            int num2 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Sum = " + add(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(choice == 2){
            System.out.print("Enter two numbers to subtract: ");
            int num1 = scan.nextInt();
            int num2 = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Subtraction = " + subtract(num1,num2));
        }
        else if(choice == 3){
            System.out.print("Enter two double numbers: ");
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Subtraction with doubles = " + subtract(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(choice == 4){
            System.out.print("Enter two numbers to multiply: ");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Multiplications = " + multiplication(num1, num2));
        }
        else if(choice == 5){
            System.out.print("Enter two numbers to divide: ");
            double num1 = scan.nextDouble();
            double num2 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Division = " + division(num1, num2));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
  }

 public static int displayMenu(int choice){
    System.out.println("1. Add");
    System.out.println("2. Subtract");
    System.out.println("3. Subtract with doubles");
    System.out.println("4. Multiple");
    System.out.println("5. Divide");
    System.out.println("6. Quit");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    int choice = scan.nextInt();

    return choice;
 }
 public static int add(int a, int b){
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
 }

 public static int subtract(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
 }

 public static double subtract(double a, double b){
    double total = a - b;
    return total;

 }

 public static double multiplication(double a, double b){
     double product = a * b;
     return product;
 }

 public static double division(double a, double b){
     double quotient = a / b;
     return quotient;
 }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this

> displayMenu(int choice);

is not getting the return so this is the fix

```
int choice = displayMenu();
```

also the method needs a change here

> public static int displayMenu(int choice){

for this

```
public static int displayMenu(){
```

Be the way for this menu is better to use `switch`

```
switch (choice){
    case 1: {
       //if(choice == 1)
       break; //if you omit this line it will do the next case
    }
    case 2: {
       //else if(choice == 2)
       break;
    }
    ...
    default {
      //else
    }
}
```

also if you wanted to show the menu again after printing a result, that `while (choice !=6)` will not work, because the menu is not in it, and this loop will be go for ever. This is the fix:

```
   int choice = -1;
   while (choice != 6){
        choice = displayMenu();
        if(choice == 1){
        ...
        else if(choice == 6){
            System.out.println("Good Bye.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, why do you put the choice -1 in the method? When I do that it says it is already defined.

Comment: you are right you don't need that, I did not see the other definition. I will edit

Comment: Ah I see now, thank you! I'm assuming it was to give the choice an initial value.

Comment: in the case of the ```while``` you need the ```choice = -1``` first because you use it in the while sentence. But in the method I fist thought you needed it cause you have it on your parameter, didn't saw it declared below. If this solution helped you, please mark as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int displayMenu(int choice){
   ...
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
   int choice = scan.nextInt();
   return choice;
}
```

You can't change the variable value in `java` in this way.

You can edit to this:

```
public static int displayMenu(){
   ...
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
   int choice = scan.nextInt();
   return choice;
}
```

And in your `main` function:

```
int choice = displayMenu();
```